# Question about how to find the local maxima and minima of a function by using Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The method of Lagrange multipliers is a strategy for finding the local maxima and minima of a function f (x, y),with (x,y) moving on a  curve Γ with equation g (x, y) = 0, we should focus on (x0 , y0) ∈ Γ where two vector (fx (x0, y0) , fy (x0, y0)) and (gx (x0, y0) , gy (x0, y0))
parallel. Which means we need to find (x0, y0) ∈ Γ to exist real number λ to make (fx (x0, y0) , fy (x0, y0)) = λ (gx (x0, y0) , gy (x0, y0)).

-Explain me why we need to focus on finding (x0, y0) like that to find  the local maxima and minima of a function f (x, y) on Γ.

-And can real number λ be zero? if yes, can you give me specific example?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.